# disable malicious bat file at logon

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

Sometimes when I logon to my workstation I find a cmd.exe window running a batch file, which disappears too fast to be eventually found. It's called start.bat in my case.

I've tried looking for it with autoruns.exe, and in the task scheduler, but I couldn't find this batch file... could you help me? Maybe it's started by services.msc?

I've got windows 8.1

Thanks

Comment: Have you check with GPE?

Comment: Thanks I've just looked, but I haven't seen any script there.
Maybe I should search for a remote user/script that starts a local process?

Comment: have you done a blanket search for *.bat on your system?

Comment: I've managed to find the batch file on a local server, but still I don't know what process/script/task actually starts the remote bat.

Comment: Are you on a corporate network?

Comment: yes it is that kind of newtork

Comment: The directory the files point to is infected with a jpg renamend to a javascript extension

Answer (score 0):

CCleaner from Pririform will give a good indication of whats running at startup. 
[image: Image showing startup item tracker on CCleaner]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: here it is, thanks!

https://i.imgur.com/HcezuhC.png